# How could I implement image channel drop with the python lib of pillow

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I need to randomly zero out 0, 1 or 2 channel of a pillow image. That means I need to randomly set 0, 1 or 2 channels of an image to 0.

How could I do that with pil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy, native PIL way of doing it by multiplying by a transform. I set the default transform so the maths looks like this:

```
newRed   = 1*oldRed  +  0*oldGreen  +  0*oldBlue  + constant
newGreen = 0*oldRed  +  1*OldGreen  +  0*OldBlue  + constant
newBlue  = 0*oldRed  +  0*OldGreen  +  1*OldBlue  + constant
```

Then I just change the `1` to `0` where I want a channel zeroed out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('input.png').convert("RGB")

# Pre-set R, G and B multipliers to 1
Rmult, Gmult, Bmult = 1, 1, 1

# Select one (or more) channels to zero out, I choose B channel here
Bmult=0

# Make transform matrix
Matrix = ( Rmult, 0, 0, 0,
           0, Gmult, 0, 0,
           0, 0, Bmult, 0)

# Apply transform and save
im = im.convert("RGB", Matrix)
im.save('result.png')
```

So, if you start with this:

[image]

and you set the Blue multiplier (`Bmult`) to zero, you'll get:

[image]

If you zero Red and Blue with:

```
Rmult = Bmult = 0
```

you'll get:

[image]

Comment: can you explain why did you used a 4 column matrix instead of 3? I am not familiar with how the matrix argument works in `convert()` so can you please explain that to me too.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S It is pretty unclear from the documentation what the 4th coefficient is -  it just declares you must pass a 4-tuple or a 12-tuple. I thought it was alpha at first, but I don't think it is now. It seems to be a simple constant that is added to the pixel after the multiplication by the other coefficients. So if you make the final coefficient in the first row 64, all your red pixels will come out 64 shades brighter. If you make the final coefficient in your second row 32, all your green pixels will come out 32 shades brighter and so on. Hope that helps.

Comment: does the placement of values at different positions, in this 3x4 matrix produces different effects? Ex. you placed the value for null channel in one of the diagonals, if you would have placed is somewhere else (let's say (0, 1)) will that have a different effect?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Have a look at the formula at the start of my answer. If you make the first row `0, 0, 1, 0, `, the second row `0, 1, 0, 0,` and the final row `1, 0, 0, 0` it will swap the red and blue channels, because `newRed` will become `1*oldBlue`.

Comment: Is variable `Matrix` a representation of `newRed`, `newBlue` and `newGreen`, in a way that `convert()` can understand

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Yes, exactly. Copy and paste the code into your editor and try applying different values to a black and a red input image and you'll soon get the hang of it.

Comment: can a single row have more then one '1' in it, and are negative values allowed?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Yes, but it may overflow if you aren't careful. If you make the first row `0, 0.5, 0.5, 0`, your new red channel will become the average of your existing green and blue channels.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Sorry, I can't chat.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my doubts (+1)

Comment: @VasuDeo.S You are most welcome! Have a play and if you get stuck, you can always ask a new question - questions, and answers, are free :-) We are all here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Numpy?
It's quite simple.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image
img = np.array(Image.open("image1.jpg")) # My Image
c = np.random.randint(3, size=1)[0] # Selecting a random channel c
img[:,:,c] = img[:,:,c] * 0 # channel c times 0.
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just not familiar with PIL, so I think maybe there is a PIL way to do it.

Comment: Or, more simply, `img[:,:,c] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:-**

```
from PIL import Image
import random

# Provide path to your image
img = Image.open(r"Image_Path")

# Converting the Image's mode to RGB, coz you wanted a random channel out of 3 channels
img.convert("RGB")

# Getting individual channels off the image
r, g, b = img.split()

# choice will store a random number b/w 0-2 we will use this value to extract a random channel
choice = random.randrange(0, 3)
null_channel = (r, g, b)[choice]

# printing the index of our randomly selected channel, ( 0 = Red; 1 = Green; 2 = Blue)
print(choice)

# changing each individual pixel value to 0, of our randomly selected channel
null_channel = null_channel.point(lambda p: 0)

# These conditions will provide the null channel to it's original channel's variable
if choice is 1:
    g = null_channel

elif choice is 2:
    b = null_channel

else:
    r = null_channel

# creating a new image with the original two channels' and our null'd channel
new_img = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))

new_img.save("new_img.jpg")
```

The above code will first convert an image's color mode to RGB, so that we can deal with 3 channels. Then it will extract the individual image channels. Then it will select a random channel of the 3 channel, and convert each pixel value of that channel to (0, 0, 0). Then it will figure out which channel was originally used (R or G or B) and then overwrite the modified values to the channel. In the end, it will create a Image Object by merging all the new channels and saves it.

**Sample Image:-**

[image]

**Image after modification:-**

[image]

After analysing the modified Image, we can clearly deduce that the red channel of the image was converted into null channel.